# Visual Studio, Xamarin, I renamed one of the projects, now screwed up

Tags: xamarin, reference, project

My solution has lost reference to one of the projects (which is the startup project).

I have unloaded and loaded the project. It's in the explorer list, but when I look at references->projects, it is not longer there. I can't add it, either.

I want to see the project in the solution references. Then I think stuff will deploy properly.

Comment: The startup project is usually not referenced by other projects - instead it is the project that references dependent projects.  But it's impossible to answer this without knowing a LOT more detail about your solution structure and what you did.

Comment: This is an autogenerated xamarin forms solution. There are 4 "projects" - the base project, an android project, an iOS project, and a UWP project. All show up in the solution explorer. However, when I right-click "references" in the solution explorer, and select "add reference", under the list of projects I no longer see the Android (startup) project. Consequently, when the thing builds it doesn't contain any android specific stuff, and so even though it kind of deploys, what's deployed isn't really an app.

Comment: Which project are you trying to add a reference to?

Comment: The android project. I had the thing working - debugging and running. Deployed and running. Then for whatever reason I changed the project name. Boom. The only thing I see that is different, now, than it was, before, is the lack of reference.

Comment: If you right click on the Android project and “add references” you should NOT see the android project listed, just the core Forms project.  Each platform project should have a ref to the core forms project.  A screen cap might help.

Comment: Okay. Must be something else went haywire with the renaming. Obviously, my memory is flawed. For whatever reason, everything builds, except for the Android project. It's set to build in the configuration manager,

Comment: What errors do you get when building?

Comment: None. It claims to have successfully deployed. The icon no longer shows up in the emulator, but if I look at apps, from settings, I see the app. My supposition is that none of the android stuff in the app is hooked up, and so it does nothing.

Comment: Delete the app from your device and completely delete the bin and obj folders from the Android project.  Yuen rebuild it and try deploying

Comment: Same deal. No error. No warning. Just a deploy that does nothing.

Comment: if you want to share your solution I can take a quick look.  Otherwise I don't know what to tell you